# I tried to know the type script. But for now show type error

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I hover the mouse pointer over the type assertion statement in Visual Studio Code, it displays

[image]

but terminal show the console result type string

[image]

Comment: you declare it as a number but you dont make it a number. Also this throws an error you can literally see in your screenshot

Comment: VS code is showing you the error in line 2, you are assigning string to a variable of type number, however the tooltip is showing type of str2 as number because you have defined type of str2 as number.

Answer (score 1):

VS code displays types error. And your code might be failed in run time (because of type mismatch).That's why type script shows error while compile your code

But Once you compile  your  typescript project,your entire folder converted as js file into **dist/index(this file contains JS code not typescript)**. You are running only dist/index folder not typescript folder Java script loosely coupled. So js ignores types error and give output.

If your are used typescript in your project.you should resolve types error.Otherwise no sense to use typescript in your project

(**Note**: If  you are using typescript,you will identify maximum run time errors in compile time.)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript which unlike javascript is strongly-typed.

However as long as your code is syntactically valid for javascript it would still generate javascript code despite it has errors(which it is doing in your case), but it will give you error in terminal while compiling and also some text editors like vs code would also give you error while development as it is in your screenshot on line no 2.

In vs code when you hover over variable `str2` it shows type is number, because you have explicitly defined type of `str2` as number, but you are assigning a string into `str2` while declaring, so you are getting an error as marked by editor.
but when you run the compiled *JS*, value of `str` is copied into `str2` which is perfectly valid in *JS* and type of `str2` returns string as it holds a string value.